# What bending test and torsion test standard are recommend for a surfboard?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, solid-mechanics

I wish to find a bending and torsion test standard for a surfboard (non-prismatic) that is roughly 2000mm long. The closest I've found for bending test is probably those ones that are designed for concrete where the specimen is really long and thick.

Comment: I strongly recommend contacting the owners of a few small surfboard manufacturing shops. You need not only torsion specs but also shear tests, and the test parameters need to reflect real-world forces applied while riding (or crashing) large waves.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be entirely surprised if there is no "official standard" for surfboards.